# Getting NaN value using php with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, nan

I'm battling my way through the development of an online quote form. I'm trying to get a price to change based on whether a checkbox is ticked or not.

The behaviour should be:
On initial page load - standard (from mysql - variable) price
When checkbox is ticked - ad $20 (from mysql) to the price
When checkbox unticked - back to the standard variable price

The behaviour i have at the moment is:
On initial page load - standard (from mysql - variable) price
When checkbox is ticked - $20 (from mysql) but not adding to the original price
When checkbox unticked - NaN

I can confirm that the prices are stored as integers in mysql e.g. 292
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code below:
php within the html page

```
<?php 
$table = $_GET['bintype'];
$pcode = $_GET['tags'];
include 'connect.php';
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $table WHERE short='$pcode'");
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($row_cnt == 0)
{
        PRINT "<p align='middle'>No go</p>"; 
 }
else
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $b = number_format($row['barrow'], 2) AND "<div id='barrowid'>"; 
  $c = number_format($row['2m3 General'], 2) AND "<div id='total_price'>";
  $d = $row['2m3 General'] AND "<div id='total_number'>";

  echo "<form id='checkboxval'><input type='checkbox' id='checkit' name='menu1'
  value=".$b.">
  </input> <div id='total'>Total:$".$d."</div>
  </form>";
  }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

javascript

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkit");

checkbox.onclick = function () {
    var subtotalField = document.getElementById("total_price");
    var checkboxes = document.forms["checkboxval"].getElementsByTagName("input");
    var subtotal = document.getElementById("total_price");
    var total = document.getElementById("total_price");

 for (var i = 0, length = checkboxes.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        var newSubtotal = parseInt(subtotal.innerHTML) + parseInt(checkboxes[i].value);
        subtotal.innerHTML = newSubtotal; 
    }
}

    total = (parseFloat(subtotal));

    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total:$" + total;
};
```

Comment: Well, `subtotal` is a DOM element, and you're adding a number?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `subtotal` and `total` are DOM elements - you need to extract the values from them before doing the arithmetic.

```
for (var i = 0, length = checkboxes.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        var newSubtotal = parseInt(subtotal.innerHTML) + parseInt(checkboxes[i].value);
        subtotal.innerHTML = newSubtotal; 
    }
}
```

Your code is a little confused. Take a look over it and remove redundant and duplicated code. Also, check this: `document.getElementById("$total_number");`. Where is element with `id = "$total_number"`?

Comment: Hi Mike W i've updated as above but i still have the NaN error when it is selected/deselected. Is there anything else you can help with? I'm really not too skilled at this sorry. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't think there's more I can do here. There are errors in your PHP script. `$b = number_format($row['barrow'], 2) AND "<div id='barrowid'>";` doesn't make sense to me: AND is a logical operator. This expression becomes the value for your checkbox, so NaN is a likely outcome of any operation on this. Your use of variables in your Javascript is confusing at best. Take a step back, and fix the obvious errors. Look at the error log for your web server as a place to start.